# Suppose $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(i,n)=\infty$ for all $i$, does that mean that $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n,n)=\infty$ as well?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Suppose that $f:\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a function such that for each $i\in\mathbb{N}$, as $n\rightarrow \infty$,
$$ f(i,n) \rightarrow 0.$$
Does this imply that $f(n,n) \rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Let

$$f(m,n)=\begin{cases}
m,&\text{if }n\le m\\
\frac1n,&\text{if }n>m\;;
\end{cases}$$

clearly $f(n,n)=n$ for all $n$, so the diagonal sequence actually blows up. Clearly one can modify the example to give $\langle f(n,n):n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ any desired behavior:

$$\begin{array}{c|cc}
m\backslash n&1&2&3&4&5&6&\ldots\\\hline
1&a_1&\frac12&\frac13&\frac14&\frac15&\frac16&\ldots\\
2&1&a_2&\frac13&\frac14&\frac15&\frac16&\ldots\\
3&1&1&a_3&\frac14&\frac15&\frac16&\ldots\\
4&1&1&1&a_4&\frac15&\frac16&\ldots\\
5&1&1&1&1&a_5&\frac16&\ldots\\
6&1&1&1&1&1&a_6&\ldots
\end{array}$$

Answer (score 6):

No. Consider $f(i, n) = \frac{i}{n}$.

Answer (score 4):

Another counterexample:

Let $f(i,n)=\delta_{in}=\begin{cases}1\text{ if } i=n\\ 0\text { otherwise }\end{cases}$.

Then $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f(i,n)=0$ for each $i\in\mathbb N$, but $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} f(n,n)=1$.

Comment: $\delta_{in}$ is the [Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta)